# how do i get the sum of my marks in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, backend

```
@require_http_methods(["GET"])
@login_required
def get_questions_parts(request):
    res = {}
    questions = models.Questions.objects.raw(
        """
             WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Q.*,PMA.*,MA.*,QP.*,QP.rowid,
         QP.part_desc <> LAG(QP.part_desc, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY QP.question_id ORDER BY QP.rowid) flag
  FROM QUESTIONS Q
  LEFT JOIN QUESTIONS_PART QP ON QP.question_id = Q.question_id
  LEFT JOIN PART_MODEL_ANSWER PMA ON PMA.part_id = QP.part_id
  LEFT JOIN MODEL_ANSWER MA ON MA.question_id = Q.question_id
)
SELECT *,
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY question_id ORDER BY rowid) number
FROM cte
ORDER BY question_id
        """
    )

    for question in questions:
        key = f'{question.question_id}_{question.part_id}'
        if key not in res:
            res[key] = {
                "key": key,
                "question": question.question,
                "question_id":question.question_id,
                "part_desc": question.part_desc,
                "part_id":question.part_id,
                "part_total_marks": question.part_total_marks,         
                "qn_total_mark": question.qn_total_mark,

            }
```

| Question_id | Question | part_desc | part_total_marks | qn_total_mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | What's a potato | It's a vegetable | 1 | 5 |
| 16 | What's a potato | It's a seed | 2 | 5 |
| 16 | 4+4 | 8 | 2 | 5 |
| 17 | What's a dog | It's a mammal | 1 | 5 |
| 17 | What's a dog | It's a pet | 2 | 5 |
| 17 | 8+8 | 16 | 2 | 5 |

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
@login_required
def edit_question_parts(request):
    req = json.loads(request.body)
    question_id=req["question_id"]
    part_id= req["part_id"]
    part_desc = req["part_desc"]
    part_total_marks = req["part_total_marks"]
    total_mark = sum([part_total_marks]) #this is wrong
    models.Questions.objects.filter(pk=question_id).update(   
        qn_total_mark=total_mark, 
        updated_by=request.user.username,
    )
    models.QuestionsPart.objects.filter(part_id=part_id).update(
        part_desc=part_desc,
        part_total_marks=part_total_marks
    )
  

    return success({"res": True})
```

in my code above what i am trying to get the sum of all the part total marks and update it into questions table above however i am not sure how to get the sum of all the part total marks as i keep getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: include the content of `part_total_marks` in your post.

Comment: @VishalSingh is this better or do i need to make a better explanation?

Comment: try to include the output of `request.POST` like `print(request.POST)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 part_total_marks = int(req["part_total_marks"])
```

as all the data in request.body, request.GET or request.POST are strings so when you update, python is adding string to an int so convert first to an int and see if it will work.